# Chrome is not playing embedded videos?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-chrome

I get below error when I load my WordPress based website ,and It is not playing my embedded video automatically.

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 412
>   (Precondition Failed)"

but in other browsers , video works perfectly.

what should I do ?